# How to write a properly query in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-hql

I have

```
    PartnerNotification quest = partnerNotificationRepository.findById(login.getAccount().getAccountId());
```

but doesn't work I get this error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<PartnerNotification> to PartnerNotification
```

and I don't really get why is this happening, does anyone have a clue what is going one and how can I fix it?
    AS I don't know what is wrong here I tried to create a query on my own but still, I am missing something here in the syntax :

```
/**
 * @param partnerId .
 * @return Notification
 */
@Query("SELECT  FROM PartnerNotification  WHERE  partner_id = :partnerId")
PartnerNotification findNotificationByPartnerId(@Param("partnerId") Integer partnerId);
```

any help is appreciated and it will be helpful!

Comment: Did you change the return type to `Optional<PartnerNotification>`? It's probably hinting you that the result can be indeed an existent `PartnerNotification ` or not, hence the `Optional`.

Comment: I need that returning type to be PartnerNotification, not Optional<PartnerNotification> ,

Comment: Unless you are working on an ancient code base, returning an `Optional` is totally fine; at some point you will have to check if your query returned something, so `quest.isPresent()` would be similar to the common `null != quest`. In any case, your query is fine, you would need to research how to change the return type, but the query is totally fine, not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should implement it.

Example:

Repository:

```
@Query("SELECT  FROM PartnerNotification  WHERE  partner_id = :partnerId")
Optional<PartnerNotification> findNotificationByPartnerId(@Param("partnerId") Integer partnerId);
```

Service:

```
PartnerNotification quest = partnerNotificationRepository.findById(login.getAccount().getAccountId())
.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

**Note**: 
you can use another solution and another Exception when accountId is not found.
Or you can use if else statement (e.g.: isPresent() )

Comment: the query sintax is wrong at least i think so , i will try and let ya know

Comment: And not doesn't work but if you have any idea what's wrong  with syntax query let me know, please

Comment: I have idea : ) do you have an entity class? I think you have one ( PartnerNotification)

e.g: @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u")
So: @Query("SELECT p FROM PartnerNotification p WHERE  p.partner_id = :partnerId") 

but I dont know whats your partner_id variable name.
Note: And you can use a method query if you want.
e.q: Optional<XY> findByColumnName(String var);

Comment: yeah that's right  i have done the same query like this :  
//    /**
//     * param partnerId .
//     * return Notification
//     */
//    @Query("SELECT p FROM PartnerNotification p  WHERE  partner_id = :partnerId")
//    PartnerNotification findNotificationByPartnerId(@Param("partnerId") Integer partnerId);